# Close form solution for finding a root

Tags: python, performance, pandas, numpy, numba

Suppose I have a Pandas Series `s` whose values sum to `1` and whose values are also all greater than or equal to `0`.  I need to subtract a constant from all values such that the sum of the new Series is equal to `0.6`.  The catch is, when I subtract this constant, the values never end up less than zero.

In math formula, assume I have a series of `x`'s and I want to find `k`

[image]

## MCVE

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from string import ascii_uppercase

np.random.seed([3, 141592653])
s = np.power(
    1000, pd.Series(
        np.random.rand(10),
        list(ascii_uppercase[:10])
    )
).pipe(lambda s: s / s.sum())

s

A    0.001352
B    0.163135
C    0.088365
D    0.010904
E    0.007615
F    0.407947
G    0.005856
H    0.198381
I    0.027455
J    0.088989
dtype: float64
```

The sum is `1`

```
s.sum()

0.99999999999999989
```

### What I've tried

I can use Newton's method (among others) found in Scipy's `optimize` module

```
from scipy.optimize import newton

def f(k):
    return s.sub(k).clip(0).sum() - .6
```

Finding the root of this function will give me the `k` I need

```
initial_guess = .1
k = newton(f, x0=initial_guess)
```

Then subtract this from `s`

```
new_s = s.sub(k).clip(0)
new_s

A    0.000000
B    0.093772
C    0.019002
D    0.000000
E    0.000000
F    0.338583
G    0.000000
H    0.129017
I    0.000000
J    0.019626
dtype: float64
```

And the new sum is

```
new_s.sum()

0.60000000000000009
```

## Question

Can we find `k` without resorting to using a solver?

Comment: Wouldn't this be better placed at https://math.stackexchange.com ?
 It is not really programming related.

Comment: @PatrickArtner though I agree this would be appropriate on that exchange, it is also right up the ally of problems you can expect to try to solve using pandas and numpy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Updated: Three different implementations - interestingly, the least sophisticated scales best.

```
import numpy as np

def f_sort(A, target=0.6):
    B = np.sort(A)
    C = np.cumsum(np.r_[B[0], np.diff(B)] * np.arange(N, 0, -1))
    idx = np.searchsorted(C, 1 - target)
    return B[idx] + (1 - target - C[idx]) / (N-idx)

def f_partition(A, target=0.6):
    target, l = 1 - target, len(A)
    while len(A) > 1:
        m = len(A) // 2
        A = np.partition(A, m-1)
        ls = A[:m].sum()
        if ls + A[m-1] * (l-m) > target:
            A = A[:m]
        else:
            l -= m
            target -= ls
            A = A[m:]
    return target / l            

def f_direct(A, target=0.6):
    target = 1 - target
    while True:
        gt = A > target / len(A)
        if np.all(gt):
            return target / len(A)
        target -= A[~gt].sum()
        A = A[gt]

N = 10
A = np.random.random(N)
A /= A.sum()

print(f_sort(A), np.clip(A-f_sort(A), 0, None).sum())
print(f_partition(A), np.clip(A-f_partition(A), 0, None).sum())
print(f_direct(A), np.clip(A-f_direct(A), 0, None).sum())

from timeit import timeit
kwds = dict(globals=globals(), number=1000)

N = 100000
A = np.random.random(N)
A /= A.sum()

print(timeit('f_sort(A)', **kwds))
print(timeit('f_partition(A)', **kwds))
print(timeit('f_direct(A)', **kwds))
```

Sample run:

```
0.04813686999999732 0.5999999999999999
0.048136869999997306 0.6000000000000001
0.048136869999997306 0.6000000000000001
8.38109541599988
2.1064437470049597
1.2743922089866828
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was sketching out on my note pad.  Maybe not exactly (-: but close enough.

Comment: You might find my answer and timings interesting https://stackoverflow.com/a/49316966/2336654

Comment: @piRSquared Interesting, indeed. And: Challenge accepted, see updated answer ;-)

Answer (score 6):

I was not expecting `newton` to carry the day.  But on large arrays, it does.

## `numba.njit`

Inspire by [Thierry's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/550094/thierry-lathuille) [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49315398/2336654)
Using a loop on a sorted array with `numba`s `jit`

```
import numpy as np
from numba import njit


@njit
def find_k_numba(a, t):
    a = np.sort(a)
    m = len(a)
    s = a.sum()
    to_remove = s - t

    if to_remove <= 0:
        k = 0
    else:
        for i, x in enumerate(a):
            k = to_remove / (m - i)
            if k < x:
                break
            else:
                to_remove -= x
    return k
```

---

## `numpy`

Inspired by [Paul's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7207392/paul-panzer) [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49314794/2336654)
Numpy carrying the heavy lifting.

```
import numpy as np

def find_k_numpy(a, t):
    a = np.sort(a)
    m = len(a)
    s = a.sum()
    to_remove = s - t

    if to_remove <= 0:
        k = 0
    else:
        c = a.cumsum()
        n = np.arange(m)[::-1]
        b = n * a + c
        i = np.searchsorted(b, to_remove)
        k = a[i] + (to_remove - b[i]) / (m - i)
    return k
```

---

## `scipy.optimize.newton`

My method via Newton

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import newton


def find_k_newton(a, t):
    s = a.sum()
    if s <= t:
        k = 0
    else:
        def f(k_):
            return np.clip(a - k_, 0, a.max()).sum() - t

        k = newton(f, (s - t) / len(a))

    return k
```

---

## Time Trials

```
import pandas as pd
from timeit import timeit


res = pd.DataFrame(
    np.nan, [10, 30, 100, 300, 1000, 3000, 10000, 30000],
    'find_k_newton find_k_numpy find_k_numba'.split()
)

for i in res.index:
    a = np.random.rand(i)
    t = a.sum() * .6
    for j in res.columns:
        stmt = f'{j}(a, t)'
        setp = f'from __main__ import {j}, a, t'
        res.at[i, j] = timeit(stmt, setp, number=200)
```

## Results

```
res.plot(loglog=True)
```

[image]

```
res.div(res.min(1), 0)

       find_k_newton  find_k_numpy  find_k_numba
10         57.265421     17.552150      1.000000
30         29.221947      9.420263      1.000000
100        16.920463      5.294890      1.000000
300        10.761341      3.037060      1.000000
1000        1.455159      1.033066      1.000000
3000        1.000000      2.076484      2.550152
10000       1.000000      3.798906      4.421955
30000       1.000000      5.551422      6.784594
```

Answer (score 2):

An exact solution, requesting only a sort, then in O(n) (well, less: we only need as many loops as the number of values that will turn to zero):

we turn the smallest values to zero while possible, then share the remaining excess between the remaining ones:

```
l = [0.001352, 0.163135, 0.088365, 0.010904, 0.007615, 0.407947,
     0.005856, 0.198381, 0.027455, 0.088989]

initial_sum = sum(l)
target_sum = 0.6

# number of values not yet turned to zero
non_zero = len(l)
# already substracted by substracting the constant where possible
substracted = 0

# what we want to substract to each value
constant = 0

for v in sorted(l):
    if initial_sum - substracted - non_zero * (v - constant) >= target_sum:
        substracted += non_zero * (v - constant)
        constant = v
        non_zero -= 1
    else:
        constant += (initial_sum - substracted - target_sum) / non_zero
        break

l = [v - constant if v > constant else 0 for v in l]

print(l)
print(sum(l))
# [0, 0.09377160000000001, 0.019001600000000007, 0, 0, 0.3385836, 0, 0.1290176, 0, 0.019625600000000007]
# 0.6
```

Comment: This gives me an idea.  I'll likely develop this into a numba solution.

Comment: @piRSquared I don't know numba, but I'd like to see it if you post it as an answer

Comment: I've added an answer and I was not expecting the results I show.

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to add an option to @piRSquared 's answer: `find_k_hybrd`

[image: figure]

`find_k_hybrd` is a mixture of the "numba" and "newton" solutions. I use the `hybrd` root finding algorithm in [NumbaMinpack](https://github.com/Nicholaswogan/NumbaMinpack). `NumbaMinpack` is faster than `scipy` for problems like this, because it's root finding methods can be within jit-ed functions.

```py
import numpy as np
from NumbaMinpack import hybrd, minpack_sig
from numba import njit, cfunc

n = 10000
np.random.seed(0)
a = np.random.rand(n)
t = a.sum()*.6

@cfunc(minpack_sig)
def func(k_, fvec, args):
    t = args[n]
    amax = -np.inf
    for i in range(n):
        if args[i] > amax:
            amax = args[i]
    args1 = np.empty(n)
    for i in range(n):
        args1[i] = args[i] - k_[0]
        if args1[i] < 0.0:
            args1[i] = 0.0
        elif args1[i] > amax:
            args1[i] = amax
    argsum = args1.sum()
    fvec[0] = argsum - t
    
funcptr = func.address

@njit
def find_k_hybrd(a, t):
    s = a.sum()
    if s <= t:
        k = 0.0
    else:
        k_init = np.array([(s - t) / len(a)])
        args = np.append(a, np.array([t]))
        sol = hybrd(funcptr, k_init, args)
        k = sol[0][0]
    return k

print(find_k_hybrd(a, t))
```